# For loops causing error ''Iterator has already started', <google.cloud.datastore.query.Iterator object at 0x108e19590>'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, datastore

I have a form with a number of loops. For each form element there is a for loop for validation errors after submitting. I also have a loop for help-text which is stored in the database. All help text is held in help_text so i need to loop through each time to get the correct help text and display. The problem is when i add more than one instance of the help_text for loop I get the error:

```
'Iterator has already started', <google.cloud.datastore.query.Iterator object at 0x108e19590>
```

I was hoping there was an approach for searching the record results in the view so as not to have to loop but any suggestions are appreciated.

```
<div>
  {{ form.Bus_Case_Stage.label }}
  <span>
    {% for help in help_items %}
      {% if help['Question'] == 1 %}
        {{ help }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </span>
  {% for message in form.Bus_Case_Stage.errors %}
     <div>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {{ form.Bus_Case_Stage }}
</div>
```